# Hide columns in SharePoint Online list for certain users

Tags: security, office365, sharepoint-online

I have a SharePoint Online list containing some columns which i want only Admins to see while letting other users to not. I have applied item level security using the Advanced Settings but i want Column Level security too.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Please use item level permission.
By enabling it you can give permission to your specified user for the particular column.

https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-enable-item-level-permissions-in-sharepoint/